# Enable component in docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose.yml somewhat like this:

```
backend:
    image: yy:latest
    ports:
        - "3000:3000"

service1:
    image: xx:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
        CONNECT_NAME: backend
        ...Further variables

service2:
    image: zz:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
        CONNECT_NAME: backend
        ...Further variables
```

However, only one of the services (1 or 2) can be chosen, but which one is needed changes often. The current solution is that I have to comment out every line of the one I am not using, and comment back the one I will use. I often modify the rest of the docker-compose.yml, so having two files isn't a solution. I am looking for something like `enabled: false`, which will make it so that the entire service will be ignored, and not downloaded, run or started. Is there something like that, or do I have to keep using comments?

Comment: why don't you have 2 compose files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about running only the services that you need?
if you want `backend` and `service1`, run:

```
docker-compose up backend service1
```

and if you want `backend` and `service2`, run:

```
docker-compose up backend service2
```

Comment: Alright, I didn't realize this was possible! That works fine for me, especially as aliases are a thing :)